# CasperJS waitForResource: how to get the resource i've waited for

Tags: wait, casperjs

```js
casper.test.begin('Test foo', 1, function suite(test) {
    casper.start("http://www.foo.com", function() {
        casper.waitForResource("bar", function(resource) {
            casper.echo(resource.url);
        });
    });

    casper.run(function() {
        test.done();
    });
});
```

`casper.echo` returns `www.foo.com` resource (the one in `casper.start`), not the one with "bar".

**How can I get the resource i've waited for with `waitForResource`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually waited for the `"bar"` resource. The problem is that `resource` inside the `then` callback function of [`waitForResource`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitforresource) is actually the page resource of the last `start` or `open` (`thenOpen`) call. It may also be the current page resource for single page applications.

If you want to wait for the resource *and* do something based on it, you would have to jump through some hoops:

```js
var res;
casper.waitForResource(function check(resource){
    res = resource;
    return resource.url.indexOf("bar") != -1;
    // or as regular expression:
    //return /bar/.test(resource.url);
}, function(){
    this.echo("Resource found" + res.url);
});
```

If you don't need to do something for the current flow, you can always do the resource handling in the event handler:

```js
casper.on("resource.received", function(resource){
    if (resource.url.indexOf("bar") != -1) {
        // do something
    }
});
casper.start(url); // ...
```

Comment: hi, thanks. I really need only the url that matched my pattern (my first parameter of `waitForResource`). Anyway i'll try if your first solution, i think it will be fine!

Comment: @artjom-b what if i want to save that resource?

Comment: @j.c Check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24591244/1816580) and the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11531448/1816580). Maybe some of it helps

Comment: @ArtjomB. thanx, i already try that solution and didn't work. In my case a PDF is dynamically loaded into an iframe, the only way i was able to save it was intercepting it with pymiproxy as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11531448/grab-the-resource-contents-in-casperjs-or-phantomjs#answer-12116959). Thanx anyway.