# Caching JS and CSS and other cacheable items to disk - PhantomJS

Tags: caching, phantomjs, offline-caching

To cache JS, CSS, images files on disk, so that PhantomJS load from local disk and not make an external ResourceRequested untill cache period expires.

I am interested in saving external hits. I have tried **--disk-cache=true** but cannot see css or js or images on cache paths :

Linux : ~/.qws/cache/Ofi Labs/PhantomJS

Windows : AppData\Local\Ofi Labs\PhantomJS\cache

Any info on this is thankful.

UPDATE :
Version 1.9.7

All i could see on *.d files in cache folders, all resources are still requested

Comment: 1.9.7, it is. All i could see on *.d files in cache folders, all resources are still requested.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grab the resource contents in CasperJS or PhantomJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11531448/grab-the-resource-contents-in-casperjs-or-phantomjs) with this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14717026).

Comment: I just tried the disk-cache option on cnn.com. The page load with an empty cache was around 12 seconds (175 resources requested) and with a warm cache around 6 seconds  (171 resources requested) with multiple trials. So it works. Are you sure that your page sets the cache-control header?

Comment: in your  warm cache, did files were in cache folder's ? When i log page.onResourceRequested, urls hits are same in both, empty and warm.

Comment: It looks like `onResourceReceived` and `onResourceRequested` are called regardless of whether the resource is cached or not. Your actual question should be answered with the above link though ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14717026) again).