# Chrome won't open from batch file in Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: windows, google-chrome, batch-file, automation, scheduled-tasks

I have a batch file that opens a webpage in chrome, and then moves and renames a file that is downloaded from the website. The batch file works when I manually run it. The file does not work when I set the file to run in the windows task scheduler

```
set date=%DATE:~10,4%_%DATE:~4,2%_%DATE:~7,2%
chrome "http://www.example.com/download_page" >>debug.log 2>&1
timeout 10
move "C:\Users\user\Downloads\export.csv" "C:\path\to\moved\file%date%.csv" >>debug.log 2>&1
```

Here is the error message that shows up in debug.log

> [21396:15752:0317/101540:ERROR:process_singleton_win.cc(335)] Lock
>   file can not be created! Error code: 32
>   [21396:15752:0317/101540:ERROR:chrome_browser_main.cc(1356)] Failed to
>   create a ProcessSingleton for your profile directory. This means that
>   running multiple instances would start multiple browser processes
>   rather than opening a new window in the existing process. Aborting now
>   to avoid profile corruption.

Comment: What userid does the task scheduler process run under?  Maybe a permissions issue?

Comment: I have tried to run the task as both my Windows Domain network user and a local user that both have admin rights on this computer. I also checked the box that says run with highest privileges. How do I check the userid of the process?

Comment: Try adding a path to debug.log

Comment: Why not instead download the page using a command-line HTTP client such as [cURL](https://curl.haxx.se/) or [cURLie](https://code.google.com/archive/p/curlie/) instead of using Chrome?

Comment: I tried a php curl solution originally. The download is triggered from a post request. There is some type of validation that requires the page be loaded with javascript for the post request to return the file. See the original question I posted here for more info. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36045745/automate-daily-csv-file-download-from-website-button-click?noredirect=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stopped trying to run Chrome in the windows task scheduler. Instead I installed the chrome extension Crontabs. I setup Crontabs to open the page at a certain time then close the tab after a few minutes. I continued to use the Windows Task Scheduler to move the downloaded file. I had to disable sleep/hibernate for this to work while I am away from my computer.
http://www.crontabs.org/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you using built-in tools such as `bitsadmin`, though some people whine about how it's depreciated and the next thing you'll see is powershell/vbs alternative.

Bitsadmin downloads it for you so you'd need no `timeout 10` if you won't run it in another instance. Sometimes it can take a second to get to the full download speed. Only disadvantage I see is automatic `cls` of your cmd screen, therefore the way with `start bitsadmin` and then you could check for `%errorlevel% equ 0` for succesful download.

```
bitsadmin.exe /transfer "<name_of_job>" "<url>" "<where to save>"
```

This way even your `move` seems unnecessary. Check `bitsadmin /?` for more info.

Comment: There is no url for the file. The file is generated from a post request, and there is some kind of validation that requires the page to be loaded with javascript for it to allow the download. I previously tried to accomplish this using curl and phantomjs. I am using the TamperMonkey chrome extension to click the download button. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36045745/automate-daily-csv-file-download-from-website-button-click?noredirect=1

Comment: Oh, sorry to hear that, these websites are painful to use. However, try to use `chrome  --incognito` or something from [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/285725/google-chrome-does-not-open)(e.g. rename those files with batch)