# Trying (with casperjs) to capture an XML file that gets downloaded when I click something

Tags: xml, casperjs

When I open [this link](http://www.fec.gov/fecviewer/CommitteeDetailFilings.do?tabIndex=3&candidateCommitteeId=C00580100&electionYr=2016) and click on the XML button in the top right section , that triggers something (and XML file called `filings.xml`) automatically getting downloaded to the downloads folder.

Using casperjs, I have been able to successfully navigate to the page and click that XML button, but I cannot figure out how to capture the `filings.xml` document that gets downloaded as a result of clicking.

Please help.

Comment: Have you seen these two questions? [downloading a file that comes as an attachment in a POST request response in PhantomJs](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16144252/1816580) and [Grab the resource contents in CasperJS or PhantomJS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11531448/1816580)